# ASP.NET MVC Html.DropDownList does not show value from SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, html-select

my application is MVC3 using ASPX views.  I have two pages, create and Edit, using the following dropdownlist:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("VesselDiameter", new SelectList(new[] { "", "1", "2", "3"}))%>
```

It works in create view and saves the data to the MS Sql table, however the value does not show in the edit view.  If I use,

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.pRCA.VesselDiameter) %>
```

I used a similar dropdownlist in another view and it worked, but the model is different:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Vessel", new SelectList(new[] { "", "1", "2", "3"}))%>
```

instead of

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Vessel) %>
```

The value is there!  Would appreciate your suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Model.pRCA.VesselDiameter mvc generates this id ("pRCA.VesselDiameter") so you should prepend pRCA to id value

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("pRCA.VesselDiameter", new SelectList(new[] { "", "1", "2", "3"}))%>
```